# AdMob get money to paypal/bank/check

Tags: android, admob

I see on admobs site they want you to take your revenue and turn it around and spend it in advertising with them. Is there anyway to just get them to deposit it to paypal or something similar?

Comment: Yes, you can extract your money: http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/payout-payment-options

Comment: Thank you, now do you know where on the admob site I would do this?

Comment: On the main Sites&Apps page, click the Transfer Funds link.

Comment: thank you, sorry i cant vote you up or accept the answer or anything

Comment: Must be > $100. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495904/admob-cant-find-transfer-funds-link-in-google-admob-panel