# Admob cant find transfer funds link in google admob panel

Tags: android, admob

I cant`t find transfer funds link in google admob, my balance more than 50 $ and my payment information fully filled, but i can not transfer funds. Help please. Where can I find it?

Comment: I cannot find the damn thing as well. What the heck?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about to google admob payment policy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to transfer to your account/paypal? if this is the case admob will only transfer funds > 100$ on the next month. No button/link is needed.

Comment: Yeah he's right. It just automatically transfers it as the next month ticks over.

Comment: I have both campaigns and apps. I want to tranfer my earnings to the campaigns. The option to transfer it is now gone.

Comment: Agreed - I was just looking for this and no sign.  This is the only information I found about it!

Comment: no we want to transfer fund to ad balance and get 20% extra to spend!!!but that option has gone forever!!!

Answer (score 2):

AdMob used to let you transfer your earnings back into your ad spend bucket, and they'd give you a 20% bonus for doing so. It looks like this is yet another nice feature that's been removed since AdMob was acquired by Google.

I've been using MoPub for ad mediation between Millennial Media, iAd, JumpTap, and many other networks (including AdMob). It's pretty nice. MoPub even has its own RTB ad marketplace.

The funny thing is that MoPub was created by former AdMob employees years ago, long before the "Don't Be Evil" empire bought AdMob.